# Code compiles in debug mode in vs 2008, not release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cuda

My cuda code compiles in debug mode, but not in release mode. When I just change the mode to release and hit compile, I get following linker errors:

```
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaConfigureCall@32 JGJJSMJMDJLMOMpartition.cu.obj
Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaGetErrorString@4 JGJJSMJMDJLMOMpartition.cu.obj
Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaEventElapsedTime@12  JGJJSMJMDJLMOMpartition.cu.obj
Error   19  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaEventSynchronize@4   JGJJSMJMDJLMOMpartition.cu.obj
Error   20  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaEventRecord@8    JGJJSMJMDJLMOMpartition.cu.obj
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaEventCreate@4    JGJJSMJMDJLMOMpartition.cu.obj
Error   22  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaThreadSynchronize@0  JGJJSMJMDJLMOMpartition.cu.obj
```

Any idea on how this can be resolved?

Comment: Did you ever solve it? I'm having the same problem under VS 2010. Libs are the same in both Debug and Release.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the list of libs you are using in debug build and make sure they (or their release equivalents) are included in the release build.

Check the library path is correct in release mode

Make sure the release libs exist and are in the right directory

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this in VS 2010. I found that

```
$(CudaToolkitLibdir)\cudart.lib
```

was missing from the Linker>Additional Dependencies project property for the Release version. I'm very puzzled why this would be the case, as it was a fresh install of VS 2010 and CUDA ToolKit 5.0.

Isn't the CUDA Toolkit installer responsible for modifying VS2010  dependencies for things like cudart.lib? I certainly didn't install the cudart.bin dependencies for Debug mode myself manually. Seems strange that the installer would skip over the Release version.